# JSONEncoder and Unicode (Django)

Tags: django

I am using JSONEncoder with Django and to encode dictionaries containing Unicode strings (JSONEncoder.encode()). Resulting JSON is injected in the web page. The problem I am facing is that the resulting JSON contains u markers next to the strings and thus is not correctly interpreted in java script

e.g. { u"key" : u"value" }

How can i get rid of it?

Thanks

Comment: Show your code. Obviously this is not valid JSON, but a simple dump of the Python variables. How are you using JSONEncoder?

Answer (score 0):

What you're working with there is the Python equivalent of your JSON object.  To get it back into JSON you want to use `dumps()`:

```
import json
mydict = { u"key" : u"value" }
print json.dumps(mydict)
```

**Edit:** I'm sorry this isn't exactly relevant to `JSONEncoder`, I will try to revise my answer.